# How do I set form size and location synchronous

Tags: c#, winforms, position

I made custom borders for my application, like the VisualStudio 2012 
There is one central mainform and 4 smaller, dynamically positioned border forms.

In the mainform I have overidden the events OnMove, OnSizeChanged, OnActivate, OnDeactivate.
In those events I set the location, size and color of the borders.

It works quite nicely, but there is some awful artifacts!
Those are the same artifacts that appear when resizing ANY window.

I made a video with my application to show what kind of atrifacts I mean.
Those appear when moving or resizing the window.

Obviously this problem IS solveable, because VisualStudio2012 does it too (*meaning that it doesn't have the problem. Just try it, resize the VS2012 window, it won't flicker*)

In my implementation I used the same way that VS2012 uses: 4 layered windows that make up the border of the form.

In case someone doesn't the glitches I'm talking about. Here's the video:
http://youtu.be/kKiPke8ruaI

What I need is a way to "synchronously" set the location and size of the 4 border windows.

Comment: I'm just curious, how did you derive this `In my implementation I used the same way that VS2012 uses`?

Comment: Visual Studio is written using WPF _not_ WinForms!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Do the tools Spy++ and IDAPro ring any bells ? ;)

Comment: You can try setting form to be `DoubleBuffered` but it is unlikely you will be able to resolve this issue...

Comment: @Felheart, they do, but I would still have to defer to the comment made by Killercam.

Comment: @Killercam: While thats true for the MAIN FORM of Vs2012 it's not true for the borders! Just look at it yourself. vs2012 uses unmanaged,layered windows to draw the borders. Unfortunately I'm unable to see how they managed to fix those resizing glitches

Comment: What are you on about. VS2012 is written using WPF, end of discussion.

Comment: @Killercam: What are _you_ on about? I already agreed with you that vs2012 is written using WPF. But I'm interested in the 4 glowing-borders (native windows, which are not drawn using WPF...)

Comment: Why would the entire application be written using WPF, then the boarders treated separately using different technology? I will tell you the answer, it is because they are drawn using WPF, like the rest of the entire application.

Comment: FFS just accept when you're wrong. I can prove that I'm right. Please open Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ViewManager.dll in dotPeek and look at the "CustomChromeWindow" type. You will see that it's a native window which has no connection with WPF at all. Your rant doesn't even have anything to do with my question. To answer your question: Obviously to save performance and memory in this performance-critical part of the application.